# Show image in fullscreen

Tags: android, fullscreen

I would like to make a Image-view application, but I cannot show the image in full screen. I can load it from SD Card, but when I click on the image, the application crashed. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
ArrayList<Integer> resultList = getIntegerArray(f);
File[] listFile;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getFromSdcard();
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.ImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);


    imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

My FullImageActivity

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(resultList.get(position));
    }
}
```

My LogCat error messages

```
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.testandroid4/com.example.testandroid4.MainActivity$FullImageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at com.example.testandroid4.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:61)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  06-19 11:41:28.456: E/AndroidRuntime(12723):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: LogCat stack trace would be helpful here

Comment: post the logcate detail or what exception created

Comment: I already updated the logcat error

Answer (score 0):

use this code on

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

and use this code in android manifest for FullImageActivity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

or else 
try this in xml like

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

for full_image_view

Comment: I already implement the code, but it is not working. the apps is still crash if I click the image

Comment: I think resultList is not having that url u should check it by LogCat

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to declare your activity in the Manifest file.

You need to add this in *Manifest.xml*:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.testandroid4.MainActivity$FullImageActivity" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I really forgot about this. But after I implement this activity, the apps still crashed. :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont see where you have resultList defined in FullImageActivity. I see it defined in MainActivity and how you populate it with getIntegerArray(f) (that I guess you are doing it correctly because the code is not here) but I cannot see this array define on FullImageActivity.

I was thinking as well that if you have an array of id's (drawables in your project). Why don't you pass the drawable id directly to the FullImageActivity from your MainActivity that is where you have the array?, like that:

```
 imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class); 
        i.putExtra("id",resultList.get(position));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

and then on FullImageActivity...:

```
// get extras in a bundle
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();    
//Create the variable where we are going o store the values passed on the array from         MainActivity
int imageResorceId=0;
// Check if the bundle is null
if(bundle!=null){
    imageResorceId = bundle.getInt("id",0);
}
//Set the imageView where we will display the drawable   
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);

//Make sure it is not 0, because if the drawable id is 0, then there was a problem retrieving the value of the array resultList on MainActivity

if(imageResorceId!=0){
   imageView.setImageResource(imageResorceId);
}
```

In case you want to implement a ViewPager for your FullImageActivity the you need the position and the array of elements but if you don't want that... why bother? ;)

Comment: I didn't see the LogCat until I publish my answer, anyway i think it is useful as well. By the way, YES, Donkey is right and you have to declare your activity in the "AndroidManifest.xml" file.

Comment: thank you, but I little bit confused. what is the mImagesResourseId and the mPosition?

Comment: I have just simplify the answer so i wrote what I think is bettter to do.

We passed from MainActivity to the FullImageActivity activity the value of the array resultList (resultList.get(position)) as an extra and we retrieve it on the FullImageActivity and we store it in the variable imageResorceId, then we use this value , in case is not 0, to set the image on the imageView (imageView.setImageResource(imageResorceId).

Is it clearer now?

Comment: I dont get it: ArrayList<Integer> resultList = getIntegerArray(f); where f is an array of file paths. Do you have your images as resource drawables inside your drawable folders?, because if you do , why do you have file paths?. And if you use images stored in the SDCard, Why are you creating an array of integers?. If you post the code of getIntegerArray(f), it would help to understand your image management.